# Add a new field, containing part of string value of another field, concated with another string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Having this `items` collection:

```
{ _id: ###, itemImage: "picture1.jpg" }
{ _id: ###, itemImage: "picture2.jpg" }
{ _id: ###, itemImage: "picture3.jpg" }
```

I want to add a new field for each document, called `itemImageThumb`, which will have a modified string of `itemImage` - e.g. for the first document it will be `picture1_thumb.jpg`.

I'm looking for a way to do that in the Mongo CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db.items.find().forEach(function(item){
    var index = item.itemImage.indexOf(".");    
    var old = item.itemImage;
    var thumb = old.substring(0, index) + "_thumb" + old.substring(index, old.length);

    //if you want add a filed
    db.items.update({_id : item._id}, {$set : {thumb:  thumb}})
})
```

the output will be:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "itemImage" : "picture1.jpg",
    "thumb" : "picture1_thumb.jpg"
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "itemImage" : "picture2.jpg",
    "thumb" : "picture2_thumb.jpg"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "itemImage" : "picture3.jpg",
    "thumb" : "picture3_thumb.jpg"
}
```